# Angular JS, output value in html attribute, fails in IE8/9

Tags: html, angularjs

I got a situation where I loop trough an array of colors and output a hex-value (through angular) into the style attribute

```
<p class="colors">
    <span ng-repeat="color in product.colors" class="product-color" title="{{ color.title }}" style="background-color: #{{ color.hex }};"></span>
</p>
```

For some reason, IE8 and IE9 doesn't recognize the background color. All I get is a element without the style attribute, but all the other attributes are there. I have triple checked the values for the variables and they are all there, and it works in Chrome/FF/Opera/Safari.

Output in IE8/9

```
<span title="White" class="product-color ng-scope" ng-repeat="color in product.colors">
```

Output in Chrome

```
<span ng-repeat="color in product.colors" class="product-color ng-scope" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;" title="Vit"></span>
```

What shall I do to make IE recognize the style attribute?

Comment: Have you tried [ng-style](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive:ngStyle)?

Comment: I have not, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ng-style` instead of `style` - IE is removing the attribute before Angular is parsing/compiling the HTML.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngStyle